# Create a new row in a dataframe, one element is a factor, the other numeric

Tags: r, function, row, factors

I am working on doing some fairly basic descriptive statistics for a large group of data. I have written a function to try and get the statistics that I need.

I want to create a new row at the bottom of a dataframe, one element of which is a factor ("total"), and the other element of which is numeric (sum of the other rows).

Here is an example of this code:

Create the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
pop = c(201:250),
age = factor(rep(c("20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69"), 10)),
year = factor(rep(c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), 10)) )
```

Write a function to do the aggregation

```
DiabMort_fun <- function(VDRpop, VDRage, nyrs, nrows) {
Aggregate_fun <- function(pop, ag1, nyrs, nrows, names_list) {
popbylist <- data.frame(aggregate(pop, by = list(Category = ag1), FUN=sum))
popbylist$mean <- (popbylist$x / nyrs)
colnames(popbylist) = names_list
popbylist[nrows,] <- c("total", sum(popbylist[2]), sum(popbylist[3]))
return(popbylist)
}


VDRbyage <- Aggregate_fun(pop = VDRpop, ag1 = VDRage, nyrs = nyrs, nrows = nrows, 
                        names_list = c("Age", "Num_pop_VDR", "Mean_pop_VDR"))
return(VDRbyage)
}
```

Run this function

```
test <- DiabMort_fun(VDRpop =  df$pop, df$age, 
                 nyrs = 5, nrows = 5)
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

> Warning message:
>   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "total") :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated

The "totals" column is now  c(NA, 11275, 2255)

What I would like it be is c("total", 11275, 2255)

Does anyone know how to create a new row in this function which will expand the factor levels to include "total"? The relevant code within the function is:

```
popbylist[nrows,] <- c("total", sum(popbylist[2]), sum(popbylist[3]))
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds you are trying to make R work like an Excel spreadsheet, which is clearly inappropriate.

Comment: You can't put in a totals like that in the bottom of the data.frame. You should calculate the totals separated from the data.frame. Object types are defined per variable (column), not by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to make the age and year columns factors; if you skip that step, and set `stringsToFactors = FALSE` in the first `data.frame()` call, your function should work.

If you really want to keep the present order and data types, you can turn the summary row into a 1-row dataframe, then bind that to the other frame.  Just make sure the column names match:

```
temp <- data.frame("total", sum(popbylist[2]), sum(popbylist[3]))
colnames(temp) = names_list
popbylist <- rbind(popbylist, temp)
```